# How to solve occurrences highlight stuck the selection word in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, highlight

I don’t know how to describe this problem. It seems that I pressed a certain key combination (unreasonable) that caused some problems with occurrences highlight.

It's a bit blurry, but if you look closely you'll notice that when I select an empty row, the highlight is still there:

[image: It's a bit blurry, but if you look closely you'll notice that when I select an empty row, the highlight is still there]

I Split the Editor. If the editor edits the same source file at the same time, the highlight will be stuck in another editor.

But if two editors are not editing the same source file at the same time, this problem will not occur.

It seem that is vscode feature but idk.

Tried:
`editor.occurrencesHighlight = false` (work, but i needed it)
`editor.selectionHighlight = false`
`Editor: Multi Document Occurrences Highlight = false and true` (both have this buggly)

and i tried to restart the vscode

Comment: Check the Setting `Editor: Multi Document Occurrences Highlight`.  If it is enabled uncheck to disbale.

Comment: the multi-document occurrence highlight feature is new. I wouldn't be surprised if there are issues with it. This looks like a bug to me. I'd suggest to raise a bug report ticket. You can use the `Help > Raise Issue` menu item to raise a bug report. If you do, please put in your issue ticket a clear procedure to reproduce the issue, and please please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.