# How to remove matching syntax highlight in split window in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a strange issue in vs code when i split the window, and click on any code or syntax , it will highlight similar code/syntax but the highlight is persistent, it wont go away, it works fine in the first window but when it gets split to the right it doesnt work if i click anywhere else in the window,

in the left side the currentCrew is highlighted now, it just wont clear.

system info

```
Version: 1.84.2 (Universal)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:52:33.687Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0
```

[image]

Comment: seems to be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77509699/11107541

Comment: I'd suggest to raise a bug report ticket. You can use the `Help > Raise Issue` menu item to raise a bug report. If you do, please put in your issue ticket a clear procedure to reproduce the issue, and please please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.